# what is the flow of django website.... what views, templates, models and forms does actually

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django web programming and struggling from 1 month to get the hang of view + models + forms + templates... and i just cant get it fully. please can anyone explain it in simple and to the point. thanks for your help.

According to me if i need to show a login page I have 2 options. 1 to use build-in UserCreadentialForms way which is in all the youtube tutorials. 2 is to use custom built. i have successfully used 1 way and now tring to use custom built forms.
for this, i goes to models and create a model of my choice (given below) then goes to run that migrate commands to actually create them in database... now tell me how to show/ fillout/ render those fields in the templates. (i am currently using admin url to register/fill out the data in fields and display them on template)

```
base template
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>
    {% endif %}

    <h1>I am base Template</h1>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

> ```
>  child html
>     {% extends "app1/base.html" %}
>
>     {% block content %}
>         <h1>Enter data</h1>
>         {% for d in data %}
>
>             <h5>Username: <h7>{{ d.username }}</h7></h5>
>     <br>
>             <h5>Email:  <h7>{{ d.email }}</h7></h5>
>     <br>
>             <h5>Logtime: <h7>{{ d.logtime }}</h7></h5>
>
>
>
>         {% endfor %}
>     {% endblock content %}
> ```

'''

> models.py from django.db import models
>
> ## Create your models here. class loginmodel(models.Model):
>
> ```
> username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
> email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
> logtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
>
> def __str__(self):
>     return self.username
> ```

'''

'''

> urls from django.urls import path from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>       path('', views.index, name='index'),
>       path('page1', views.page1, name='page1'),
>       path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
>       path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
>       path('base/', views.base, name='base'), ]

'''

'''

> views.py from django.shortcuts import render from .models import
>   loginmodel from django.http import HttpResponse
>
> data = [
>       {
>           'username': 'Haider',
>           'email': 'haider@gmail.com',
>
> ```
> },
> {
>     'username': 'ghufran',
>     'email': 'ghufran@gmail.com',
>
> } ]
> ```
>
> def index(request):
>       return HttpResponse("Home Page app1.views.")
>
> def page1(request):
>       return HttpResponse("page1 app1.views ")
>
> def dashboard(request):
>       context = {
>           'data': loginmodel.objects.all()
>       }
>       return render(request, 'app1/print.html', context)
>
> def base(request):
>       return render(request, 'app1/base.html')
>
> def about(request):
>       return render(request, 'app1/about.html')
>
> def loign(request):
>       log =

'''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot to tell but to cut everything in short,

Views - It contains your logic function, all the main function goes to views.py of the app

Models - It contains the schema of your database that is the overall structuring of the database.

Template - It contains your frontend content, basically the html part that we are all familiar with.

Forms - Now Forms is something that can be done using django or without it also but django_form make thing easy so Form have elements like fields as usual which is associated with a Model. Django Form make thing ridiculously easy and fast.

[image]

Hope this helps!